# How can I swap the names of two files on the command line?

Tags: command-line, rename

I am working in bash under Ubuntu 10.04 at the moment, but the solution would be interesting in other environments as well (e.g. Windows cmd.exe). I would typically rename the first file with a temporary name, rename the second file with the first name and finally rename the temporary file with the second name. Is there and idiom or program for doing this in one step?

Example (bash):

```
$ mv file1 tmp; mv file2 file1; mv tmp file2
```

Comment: This is a basic variable [swap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swap_%28computer_science%29). :)

Comment: Sure, but wouldn't it be nice to just type `swap file1 file2` instead. I guess I'll just right a bash script to do that.

Answer (score 5):

I created the shell script below to accomplish this task, but I'm still curious if there are standard methods already available.

```
#!/bin/sh
tmp=`mktemp`
mv $1 $tmp
mv $2 $1
mv $tmp $2
```

I named it swap, made it executable and placed in my path. That allows for the following syntax.

```
swap file1 file2
```

Comment: Uh, I didn't use a fixed name. See ( http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/mktemp/ ).

Comment: My bad, I somehow read the backtcks as ".

Comment: No problem. I don't do shell scripting often. So, your use of the PID variable ($$) was actually very helpful. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$ mv old_file tmp_file && mv current_file old_file && mv tmp_file current_file
```

As seen on SO https://stackoverflow.com/a/1115909/1478950

Safer, as you won't loose files if the initial `mv` fails.